# (Windows 10) All windows move after waking up monitor

Tags: windows-10, hdmi, window, displayport, bug

**OS:** Windows 10

**GPU:** AMD Radeon 6800 XT (Radeon software driver version: 2.12.1)

I have two display port monitors plugged into my GPU. Display Port 1 is set as my main monitor.

Everything was working (mostly fine). The only problem I had was after I wake my monitors up, all of the Windows on my Desktop from Display Port 2's monitor would move to Display Port 1's monitor.

I only used a few windows on Display Port 2's monitor so I just manually moved them each time.

Now I've plugged in an HDMI monitor into my GPU. I extended Display Port 1's desktop to the HDMI port Monitor (Displays: 1|3, 2)

Now every time I wake, the windows shift towards Display Monitor **2** after wake.

This is actually incredibly frustrating. I usually have lots of Windows open on my main monitor (Display Port 1) and I'm getting tired of having to move them.

What can I do? Is there a way to fix this, without using a third party program? I just want all my windows to be on the same monitors they were on before they went to sleep.

Comment: Wake the displays manually before the computer. It's a timing issue. Unless someone has a method of extending the time the system waits before declaring the display 'disconnected'.

Comment: I'm saying the computer is already awake, the monitors themselves went to sleep. After I wake the monitors (simply moving the mouse or pressing a key on the keyboard), the windows have shifted.

Comment: We're not using 'wake' in this instance in the same way as the semi-hibernated computer 'sleep' The displays themselves don't go to sleep if there's still a signal. The computer has terminated the signal &/or told the displays to sleep. When you 'wake' the computer from this stage, it expects the displays to also wake. It gives them 'xx' time to do this, after which it declares them lost.

Comment: When you say wake the displays manually, do you mean press the power buttons on the monitors every time?

Comment: Do "something" to prime them. What precisely that is will be dependant on the displays themselves. Mine I can wake by switching the expected input, twice. What you need is that there is zero wait-time when the computer starts to look for them.

Comment: I mean this technically works but surely there's a better solution? It's so much easier to just wake the computer up. This didn't happen before with just HDMI displays but now it happens with DisplayPort monitors.

Will there ever be a fix for this on Windows? This doesn't happen ever on my Linux distros.

Comment: I believe Windows 11 has this feature but why doesn't Windows 10?

Comment: Displays have different wake speeds depending on how they're connected. I can repro the same issue with two identical monitors simply by changing their connection type, or even reverseing which cable goes to which screen.

Comment: Yes but clearly this must be a Windows 10 issue, no? Windows 11 seems to have a feature that fixes it, and this never happens on my Linux distros.